# Disable reflection on mesh

Tags: 3d-view

Is it possible to turn off the reflection on the meshes?

[image]

Comment: you can turn up roughness and turn down metallic value of your material....this is one way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the setup to disable reflection... ;)

[image]

We can only see objects because they either emit their own light, or they reflect light from another light source. What you mean, however, is probably the mirroring ability of a surface - which is caused by consistency of the surface, simulated by the roughness input of Principled BSDF shader:

[image]

In some cases decreasing *metallic* may actually produce an opposite result...

[image]

Comment: Thanks Chris and Markus, with the explanation from Markus, a light came on again, the principle of light and how we see things

Comment: Might be nice to have such gifs in the manual... great!

Comment: @MIck Another thing might be, if you maybe want sharper reflections (so turning up the roughness is no option) but not so predominantly visible, you can turn down the _Specular_ value.

Comment: Actually, decreasing _Metallic_ is not really producing an opposite result. When you increase the roughness, the specular reflection gets blurred until it's looking completely diffuse. But decreasing the _Metallic_ value doesn't make it any more or less rough. The metallic property of an object tints the reflection with the base color, so the only reason the reflection seems to be less or not visible with a black metallic surface is caused by coloring the (still sharp) reflection with black.

Comment: Thanks Gordon Brinkman I will try that

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I were only referring to the end result - which is that less of the world is perceptually visible on the Susanne (at least to me). I honestly never investigated the actual algorithm behind Principled BSDF. This answer clearly could be improved by a lot.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Well, I sometimes think it would be interesting to investigate why things are behaving like they do and would like to explain more in-depth... because some special cases that come up in questions might lead to a solution but not give an understanding of the general function or use. But after all this is no tutorial site and there are so many tutorials out there...